# c# log everything being written in console

Tags: c#, logging, batch-file

I have a server that's coded in c#, I was wondering.. Is there a way to log everything that pop ups in the console without having to go every single line where it says Console.WriteLine and add StreamWriter or whatever?

I'm going to use this:

```
 *.exe > *.log
```

but I want to be able to see the console while logging.. any ideas?

Comment: `D:\>YourApp.exe > output.txt`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) to write both to console and file:

```
Trace.WriteLine("Hello");
```

To setup both console and file output use following on start of application:

```
Trace.AutoFlush = true;
Trace.Listeners.Clear();
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("log.txt"));
```

Same can be configured from config file

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <clear/>
      <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
      <add name="file" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="log2.txt"/>
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

---

But consider to use some logging framework line [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) (available from NuGet). I think that is what you need - you can write both to console and file, and many other targets, which you can add and remove by changing config file:

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="Console" name="console" layout="${time} ${message}"/>
  <target xsi:type="File" name="file" fileName="${basedir}/logs/log.txt"/>
</targets>
<rules>   
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file,console" />    
</rules>
```

Usage:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
// after you obtained logger
logger.Info("Hello");// message goes to all targets
```

Answer (score 1):

The feasibility and ease of this depends upon how your program is launched.

If your program is launched from a command line, batch script or shortcut, you can simply redirect the output. Something like this:

```
myprogram.exe > mylogfile.txt
```

If you are writing a program that launches another program, you could accomplish the same thing by redirecting the output in code. See [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)

Comment: But I need it to show the actual console too, if I use that it will just save but it won't show the console in the window.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is to use something like `tee`.  It is designed to let you see console output as well as redirect that same output to a file.

It doesn't come with Windows, but it and other useful tools are available at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net.  Certainly beats rewriting your code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Write a method that when you call, it calls  both `Console.WriteLine()` and whatever method you are using to log - then call that method instead of `Console.WriteLine()`

```
public class Logger
{
public static void WriteLine(string s)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
  myLogger.WriteLine(s);
{
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really help tbh and this isn't valid C#.

Comment: It's a code snippet - meant to give the OP an idea how to implement.

Comment: but what is `MyLogger`? I believe the OP is looking how he can log everything, you state `write a method that calls whatever it is you use to log` when the OP has not stated that they are already using an existing logging library. Also, this is still not valid C# (you have you invalid braces).

Comment: Like i just said, it gives the an OP an _idea_ on how to implement. myLogger can be whatever they are using to log. The code is not meant to be thrown directly into a compiler, but more of pseudo code, that will ignite an idea of their own. Apologies on the wrong curly bracket. didn't realize the curly bracket police were on high alert today.

Answer (score 0):

run cmd, and execute your exe like this

c:\Users\you> c:\Bin\yourexecutable.exe > c:\Log\yourexecutable.Log

Comment: But I need it to show the actual console too, if I use that it will just save but it won't show the console in the window.

Comment: I suggest you direct the output of the console to a log file, like C:\myexe.exe>>C:\mylog.log and write a batch file to read the log file in a loop, echo off
:while
cls 

type c:\mylog.log
ping 10.10.10.10 -n 1 -w 10000 > nul
goto while

Comment: This is not the efficient way to log your trace.